# PlayFramework schedule job does not work?

Tags: java, playframework

I config a Job to execute every 3 hours day time, below is cron config:

```
@On("0 0 10-20/3 * * ?")
```

But it didn't work

This is my `play staus` output:

```
Requests execution pool:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Pool size: 20
Active count: 0
Scheduled task count: 876
Queue size: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer:

```
@On("0 0 10-20/3 * * ?")
```

didn't means the job will run 4 times(10, 13, 16, 19), play will wait for the first job until it ends, and then wait 3 hours to run next job.

so, if this job spend 10 hours, the job will only execute once per day.